# Twitter API V2 - Request failed 429: too many requests

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, twitter

I'm using the Twitter API V2, and I'm trying to retrieve all the followers of a specific user.

According to the Twitter API docs, the maximum number of followers I can retrieve in a single request for a specific user is 100.

Assuming the user has more than 100 followers; to retrieve the next 100 followers, I need to make another request and pass a pagination token as a parameter in my next request.

The problem is that the Twitter API's rate limit on retrieving followers is 15 requests per 15 min window.

So, if I try to retrieve all followers of a user who has 1500 followers or more, I get a 429 status code error saying "Too many requests".

Is there any solution or trick to get over this error? because most of the time I would want to retrieve followers of users who have more than 1500 followers.

I'm using JavaScript.

Comment: The trick would be to wait for the next 15 minute window after you have used the initial request limit, and then continue to retrieve more pages.

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait your 15 minutes with the standard API from Twitter. But you could try and request premium API access with this link:
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/premium